# Device for Preview (D) - how to add custom device for preview WITHOUT adding a virtual device?

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, preview

I am trying to make an app for a specific phone which is 6,2inch and 1080x2246 display. To debug and test my app I am using this exact phone by USB and ADB - so there is no point for me to install a bunch of useless stuff for me to run virtual device. So that is is why I am asking this question - can I make a custom Device for Preview for XML files in android studio WITHOUT making a virtual device(without Android Emulator and without downloading a bunch of GB of emulator stuff)?

I have made Hardware Profile and restarted the Anrdoid studio = nothing worked and this phone did not appeared in "Generic Devices" but appeared in "Select hardware - choose device definition" but I was expecting it to appear in "Generic Devices" or, at least, under "Custom" tab(which is seen after clicking on "Device for Preview (D)" button.

Answer (score 0):

In design mode, you can click and drag at the bottom right corner and set the screen size as you want.

[image: Where to click]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I have tried but I can not find a way to make it exactly 1080x2246px or 412x856dp. Is there a way to make it to those numbers?
Thank you!

Comment: If you want that exact size of 1080x2246, then you should make a custom device. In the design section, you can see an AVD selected in the properties panel. If you click on that drop-down and scroll down, you will find a "Add Device Definition" button. There, you can customize your AVD screen as you want without downloading anything (just select an API that has already been downloaded to your computer).

Comment: "that has already been downloaded to your computer" - that is the point, no API was downloaded to my pc and I do not want to download it, that is why I am looking for a way not to download it. Thank you!

Comment: Mmmm. As far as I know, there is no other way except to download it.

Comment: So annoying that it doesn't show you dp when you're dragging that around.